# Access ExtJS grid's column model from other file

Tags: properties, model, extjs, grid

I have an ExtJS grid that has a button set up in it. The button triggers a function that's defined into other JS file that's included in the grid page. The function triggers ok but in that function I want to get the columns count like this:

```
grid.getColumnModel().getColumnCount()
```

The problem is that I get an error like: grid.getColumnModel is not a function.

In PHP I would make a "global $ext" and then access that function. How can I do this in Ext ? How can I access the grid from other file ? What needs to be defined ?

Thank you.

Comment: Note: `getColumnModel` doesn't exist in Ext 4. Not related to problem here, but this was the answer that came up when I wanted to figure out how to access the columns from a grid in Ext 4.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you define the grid object? Did you do it like this:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel(...);
```

If so, the grid object is not in global scope. Remove the "var" and see if it helps.

Comment: Damn, I thought this is something to do with global accessing the Ext objects or something.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a scope issue. See variable [scope in JavaScript](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/).

Basically, you can do:

```
my_global_grid = ... // accessible in the current ~global~ context (document, window)
var my_local_grid = ... // accessible only in the function
window.my_window_global_grid = ... // accessible in the same window
```

Comment: Thanks. Tommi answered first, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You might also pass the grid object into your function as an argument:

```
function myFunction(arg1,arg2,grid){
   ...
    var count = grid.getColumnModel().getColumnCount();
   ...
}
```